# Android Studio, Trying to hide TabLayout, StatusBar, SupportActionBar and an unknown bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, show-hide, android-tablayout

So at the click of a button I want to hide all bars on top of screen, to disappear. At another click of button I want them all to reappear again. I successfully did that and have the following bars to hide on button click: Status Bar, TabLayout tab fragments, Support Action Bar. Here's what I have.[image]

When I click my "Start" button ^, all these bars on top, hide. But only 1 is left ...

[image]

I tried hiding the "getActionBar" but that bar that's left is not it.

According to my styles.xml when I change the color of the 'ColorPrimaryDark', that's the bar that's left:

[image]

I tried hiding PopupOverlay and AppBarOverlay, and get nothing.

Here's my XML file for this:

[image]

So what can be this mysterious bar that's left? I'm not asking for code, I'm only simply trying to find out if anyone knows what it can be that's left?

Comment: No, I hid the getSupportActionBar(). It appears I need to hide  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>  from styles.xml, if possible? Or make the colorPrimaryDark transparent on button click.